# Java template for checking that value was set

Tags: java

In Java I have a bunch of variables (of different types) that I would like to check that they have been set before using them, and if they have not then the result is always the same and I want to throw an error that'll be caught higher up.  In theory the code is designed that this should NEVER happen, but the consequences of a bug making it happen are too great to leave it to just unit testing.

I was thinking of just making a template that has a get() and set() function.  The set would set the value and set a boolean to let it know it has been set and the get() would check the boolean and return the value or throw an error. something like:

```
Class ImportantInfo<T> {
   private T t;
   private beenSet = false;
   public T get(){
      if(beenSet) return t;
      else throw error;
   }
   public void set(T value){
    t =value;
    beenSet = true;
   }
}
```

Is this the correct and best approach?  Are there other, possibly better, ways?  I worry I am over engineering the solution or that a template this straightforward might already exist in Java?

Comment: what's wrong to check if its null or not?

Comment: The normal case would be if (theVar!=null) { theVar.doSomething(); } and with your approach you need to try { importantInfo.get().doSomething(); } catch (Exception e) (...) . Much harder to read

Comment: Why not enforce it by checking, in the constructor of your object, that the property is not null? Or simply throw an exception from the getter itself if the value is null?

Comment: Have you considered thread safety?

Comment: Maybe you could set it within the constructor directly, so that it can be `final`?

Comment: I would have a  validation layer. It would keep the beans themselves simple, and use an explicit validation class that is called at a key point, and throws if any of your important info is null. That would be much easier to test and maintain.  And, if using something like Spring, validation layers are part of the framework

Comment: The problem with checking for null or not is that it is prone to a single area of code where the check is not made (not by design but an accident).  As  I mentioned I considered it crucial to make sure that can't happen by mistake.

Comment: gfelisberto, it does have more typing; although the exception would be caught much higher up in the chain so I would have importantInfo.get().doSomething() only almost everywhere, which is less error prone than (theVar!=null) { theVar.doSomething(); }

Answer (score 3):

One approach to do this would be to use [Java `Optional`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html). `Optional`s represent a value that may or may not be present.

- `Optional.empty()` represents a value that is not present
- The `.get()` method gets a value if it is present
- The `isPresent()` checks if a value has been set or not.

The main advantage of using `Optional` over simply checking for `null` is that optional forces you to use `.get()` so you don't accidentally call a null value that hasn't been set.

In your particular case, I would initialize all the values at the top of the class to `Optional.empty()` and then use `.isPresent` to make sure they were set.

**Note: This will only work with Java 8**

(Apparently `Guava Optional` will work in versions less than 8 (see Tom's comment - I have no experience with this)

Comment: It would be a good idea to mention that this will only work in Java 8.

Comment: @ChetanKinger Will do

Comment: [Guavas Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) can be used if the Java version is <= 7.

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways, but the approaches that I would normally find useful:

1. checking if its `null`, personally I just use this, if `null` I assume its not been set otherwise its been set, then you can also give the user the responsibilities (optional)
2. instead of having `setter` method, you can use the `constructor`. this way you ensure that the value has been set before even being able to use the `get` method.

Comment: I felt that checking for null was prone to the error of accidentally not checking it one place.  Setting it in the constructor doesn't work because I don't always know what the value should be (most of the values are user entered).

Comment: @Michael I think its over engineering the code. most of API and library classes in java simply return null (or throw Exception ) if something not set. its my personal opinion. if something is null, its fault resides in  whatever application that is using it not the library/API.

Comment: @Michael if absolutely NULL must not occur anywhere else. using getter and setter is bad to begin with.